# Can't use scroll-function in IntelliJ

Tags: lenovo-laptop, scrolling, intellij-idea

I find that I can't scroll in IntelliJ ... which is annoying when I code. Wondering if anyone has any tips on what the problem might be?
- So I can only navigate with the arrow keys.

My computer is a Lenovo Yoga 710 and I have had the problem since I downloaded IntelliJ a year ago. Have several people taking the same course as me with the same PC, though without the same problem.

Relevant info: I can scroll on all websites and in other programs on the computer.

Have heard with lecturer and others, but can't find a solution. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and only solution I have found is to re-install software.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping it didnt come to that :)